# convert finance calculation to Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I think I'm just being a bit dense here but it was many, many years since I did math formulae.

I'm trying to convert the following finance calculation to javascript, this is supposed to calculate monthly repayments based on total borrowed, interest rate and amount of monthly repayments:

1000 borrowed. 0.015 is 6.85% divided by 12. 24 is amount of months to pay

M=1,000(1+.015)<sup>24</sup>(.015)/[(1+.015)<sup>24</sup>-1]= $49.92

This is what I've got at the moment and it's not coming up with the correct result:

```
var m = 1000 * Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) * 0.015  / Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) - 1;
```

This is coming up with the absolutely incorrect answer of 14 so I can only presume that my brackets are wrong somewhere.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `var m = 1000 * Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) * 0.015  / (Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) - 1);`

Comment: Yep! Put it as the answer and I'll give you the point.

Comment: @jimbeeer I don't think thats a good idea

Comment: why not? he was officially the first person to answer.

Comment: That's ok. The point is that the last expression needs parenthesis (as expressed in your equation), but not in the JavaScript expression. Any of the answers below are acceptable :)

Comment: Yes, you've calculated 1000*0.015-1 = 14.  The expressions Math.pow in numerator and denominator resolve to 1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put parentheses around the denominator to be consistent with the formula you showed us:

```
var m = 1000 * Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) * 0.015  / (Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) - 1);
```

Because of order of operator precedence rules, your current code is actually the same as this:

```
var m = (1000 * Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) * 0.015  / Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24)) - 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a typographical mistake or not. But still wondering if we should answer or a mere comment is enough'

Comment: @Rajesh It's on the fence.  If the OP really doesn't know operator precedence, then giving an answer might be defensible.

Answer (score 2):

You missed out brackets around the denominator:

```
var m = 1000 * Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) * 0.015  / ( Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) - 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, This is following BODMAS rule

```
var m = 1000 * Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) * 0.015  / (Math.pow(1 + 0.015, 24) - 1);
```

Comment: Please refer other answers before posting answer

Comment: Yeah was posting and then suddenly all appeared